# Which websites are useful for looking for a room in a shared flat in Germany?

Tags: germany, accommodation

I'm spanish and I'm moving for some time to Heidelberg, Germany in a few months. I'm already looking for a place to live but I don't know exactly how.

I don't speak German so I'm looking for websites in english preferably. I know that is very usual in Germany just to rent a room in a flat and that is my choice.

I have been reccomended [WG-Gesucht](http://www.wg-gesucht.de/en/wg-zimmer-in-Heidelberg.59.0.1.0.html) but I would like to know which are the standard websites to look for a place to live in Germany because I haven't found anything that suits me in WG so far.

Comment: wg-gesucht.de is actually one of *the* standard websites when you're looking for a shared apartment in Germany. That said, the housing situation in Heidelberg is rather difficult. In this city, the rental prices are among the highest in Germany. It might be relevant to your question what you'll be doing in Heidelberg and how long you're planning to stay? Perhaps there is a more specific answer to your question...

Comment: I think the website of some universities might offer hints and suggestions for residence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[wg-gesucht.de](http://wg-gesucht.de)** is actually one of *the* standard websites when you're looking for a shared apartment in Germany.

Generally speaking, the term you'd be searching for is **WG** (short for **Wohngemeinschaft**). This way, you'll find a few more like [wg-suche.de](http://wg-suche.de), [wohngemeinschaft.de](http://wohngemeinschaft.de), [easywg.de](http://easywg.de) etc.

You can also try a few **general real estate websites** like [immobilienscout24.de](http://immobilienscout24.de) or [immonet.de](http://immonet.de) -- they also provide the option to explicitly search for WGs.

That said, the housing situation in Heidelberg is rather difficult. In this city, the rental prices are among the highest in Germany.

It could also be worthwhile to check **local newspapers**. For Heidelberg, this would be the Rhein-Neckar-Zeitung. This newspaper is also availble online, and in the real estate section there is an option to [search](http://www.rnz.de/immobilien/mietgesuche.html) for a "WG-Zimmer" (room in a shared apartment).

---

It might be relevant to your question what you'll be doing in Heidelberg and how long you're planning to stay:

If you'll be a member of the University, check with the [International Relations Office](http://www.uni-heidelberg.de/courses/contact/aaa/aaa_services.html) to see if they can provide any further assistance. You can also try contacting the [international department](http://www.studentenwerk.uni-heidelberg.de/de/international_kontakt) of the Studentenwerk Heidelberg.

(In Germany, a Studentenwerk is responsible for providing additional services to students of a university, most notably housing, i.e. dorms.)